All apps not respond in Ubuntu 22.04
I had a very bad problem on my thinkpad t490s computer.
I was using everything normally but suddenly one app became unresponsive, not stopping there, other apps also froze and couldn't respond.
What else can I do, after about 3 minutes they automatically turn off, no app in the system can start and I turn off the device with the Power off button, and restart it I get the following message
[3540.263469] systemd [119288) "gou-manager.service: Failed to execute /usr/bin/gpu-manager: Input/output error 
[3540.264585] systemd [119288]: gpu-manager.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/gpu-manager: Input/output error 
[3540.268219] systemd[1]: Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
[ 3540.276757] systemd [119289]: gdm.service: Failed to execute /usr/share/gdm/generate-config: Input/output error
3540.2778151 systemd [119289]: gdm.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/share/gdm/generate-config: Input/output error [ 3540.280870] systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
[ 3541.515297] systemd [119290]: gpu-manager.service: Failed to execute /usr/bin/gpu-manager: Input/output error
[3541.516071] systemd [119290]: gpu-manager.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/gpu-manager: Input/output error [ 3541.518792] systemd[1]: Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
[ 3541.526968] systemd [119291]: gdm.service: Failed to execute /usr/share/gdm/generate-config: Input/output error
[3541.527880] systemd [119291]: gdm.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/share/gdm/generate-config: Input/output error [ 3541.529610] systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
[ 3542.767048] systemd [119292]: gpu-manager.service: Failed to execute /usr/bin/gpu-manager: Input/output error
[3542.768157] systemd [119292]: gpu-manager.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/gpu-manager: Input/output error
[ 3542.771852] systemd[1]: Failed to start Detect the available GPUS and deal with any system changes.
3542.7806061 systemd [119293]: gdm.service: Failed to execute /usr/share/gdm/generate-config: Input/output error
3542.781680] systemd [119293]: gdm.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/share/gdm/generate-config: Input/output error
[ 3542.782991] systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
[ 3544.015539] systemd [119296]: gpu-manager.service: Failed to execute /usr/bin/gpu-manager: Input/output error
[ 3544.016641] systemd [119296]: gpu-manager.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/gpu-manager: Input/output error
[ 3544.020192] systemd[1]: Failed to start Detect the available GPUS and deal with any system changes.
[ 3544.028457] systemd [119297]: gdm.service: Failed to execute /usr/share/gdm/generate-config: Input/output error
3544.029530] systemd [119297]: gdm.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/share/gdm/generate-config: Input/output error [3544.030971] systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
[ 3545.271348] systemd [119298]: gpu-manager.service: Failed to execute /usr/bin/gpu-manager: Input/output error
[ 3545.272389] systemd [119298]: gpu-manager.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/gpu-manager: Input/output error
[ 3545.275476] systemd[1]: Failed to start Detect the available GPUS and deal with any system changes.
[3545.282710] systemd [119299]: gdm.service: Failed to execute /usr/share/gdm/generate-config: Input/output error
[3545.283611] systemd [119299]: gdm.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/share/gdm/generate-config: Input/output error
[ 3545.286495] systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
[ 3546.492526] systemd[1]: Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
[3546.493635] systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
[ 3546.528606] systemd [119301]: plymouth-quit.service: Failed to execute /usr/bin/plymouth: Input/output error
[3546.529704] systemd [119301]: plymouth-quit.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/plymouth: Input/output error
[3548.834523] systemd [119304]: user-runtime-dir@1000.service: Failed to execute /lib/systemd/systemd-user-runtime-dir: Input/output error
[ 3548.835692] systemd [119304]: user-runtime-dir@1000.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-user-runtime-dir: Input/output error

After that, I had to hard turn it off with the power button, and my computer worked normally, some time later, maybe when I use a lot of Ram or CPU, it will happen again, it was so bad.
Please someone help me

looks a lot like storage failure to me, not related to CPU or RAM usage (unless you're using more RAM than you have, leading to swapping, leading to earlier noticing of that failed storage.

Looks like you have a problem with hardware on your computer due to the I/O errors. Could be a failing drive.
I previously thought it was a Linux swaplock, but I wasn't able to see the I/O errors at first.

Yes, exactly my hard drive was broken, I had to replace a new hard drive and lost all my data -_-
